# How to import DB2 database to Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, db2

I'm pretty new to SQL and on collage we used IMB DB2 running on Linux. So i have [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k6rpc778w76ll2o/AAAnXftHjvVVFaB4LQRIUCrDa/3.%20Godina/5.%20semestar/Relacione%20Baze%20Podataka/Vezbe/2015%20-%2016%20Vezbe%2C%20asis.%20Mirjana%20Maljkovic/Materijal%20za%20pravljenje%20baze%20VSTUD?dl=0)

instruction set to import database to DB2. I started using SQL server now, so i wonder is there a way to use this setup to import database to SQL server. There are some syntax differences and .ixf files that i don't know how to use.

Comment: The simplest way is to ensure that DB2 has an OLE DB interface and use linked servers.  See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You can't export to ixf (because that's a format that only DB2 understands). What you need to do (if using export/import anyhow) is to export to a text format:

```
db2 "export to mytable.csv of del select * from mytable"
```

If you need another separator (say ;) you can specify that by:

```
db2 "export to mytable.csv of del modified by coldel; select * from mytable"
```

Then you probably have to convert the file to windows format:

```
#> unix2dos mytable.csv
```

Move the file to your windows server and use an import utility (bcp?) to import the data.